# Could there be any valid reason for this variable being defined in the middle of a class?

Tags: c#

I've taken over a C# project (original developer gone) which contains a form named "MainForm" and a class containing several members defined at the top of the class, followed by the classes constructor and several methods. In between two of the class methods is this:

```
MainForm main = (MainForm)Application.OpenForms["MainForm"];
```

The var "main" is referenced throughout the class - both before and after where it is defined. Is there any valid reason why it should be defined where it is rather than putting it at the top of the class along with the other declarations? IOW, instead of this:

```
    . . .
} // GeneratePackets()

MainForm main = (MainForm)Application.OpenForms["MainForm"];

private void RunFile(string unit, string brand, string begindate, string enddate, string delvbegdate, string delvenddate, SQLServer sqlDAL, Image picObject)
{
    . . .
```

...why not this:

```
class CRPacketGenerator
{
    private int _commandTimeout = 30000;
    private string privateModuleName;
    private bool privateDisposedBoolean;
    MainForm main = (MainForm)Application.OpenForms["MainForm"];
    . . .
```

?

Comment: Maybe it was refactored out and not moved?

Comment: There is no technical reason for putting it in one place vs. the other. I usually put all my instance variables at the top of the class so they're easy to find.

Comment: @CraigW. Okay, but it sure seems like Winchester Mystery Code.

Comment: It is functionally equivalent wherever it appears in the file. My guess is the developer was working on a function that needed it and instead of scrolling all the way up to the top of the class, they added it above the method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The member is not `static`, so [the position of the line of code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645757(VS.71).aspx) shouldn't matter.
- The variable has no access modifier while other class members are explicitly `private`
- There is no comment around to explain it

So I would assume there is no actual reason, maybe some unfinished refactoring (maybe the variable was *inside* the scope of a method and has been moved out of it).